# How to python and excel calculator

Tags: python, excel

This is my Python code. I have a 10.xlsx file and I have about 160 rows of data in the E, F, and G columns in the Excel file. I want to create a new Excel file called 11.xlsx by adding one column to each column of E, F, and G, and writing it to column H, how do I modify the code?

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('10.xlsx')

ws = wb.active


for row in range(1,ws.max_row):
    if(ws.cell(row,1).value is None):
        break
    print(ws.cell(row,1).value)


wb.save("11.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the input columns and the desired output?

Comment: Yes. The input columns will be E, F, G, and the data is composed of numbers. Each row is added to the H column.

Comment: Okay, so your idea is to sum values in columns E, F and G and then output the sum in column H. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: halp me.... plz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code stores the sum of columns E, F and G of file 10.xlsx into column H of file 11.xlsx.

```
import openpyxl

wb_10 = openpyxl.load_workbook('10.xlsx')
wb_11 = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws_10 = wb_10.active
ws_11 = wb_11.active

colE = ws_10['E']
colF = ws_10['F']
colG = ws_10['G']

for i in range(max(len(colE), len(colF), len(colG))):

    if colE[i].value == None: colE[i].value = 0
    if colF[i].value == None: colF[i].value = 0
    if colG[i].value == None: colG[i].value = 0

    ws_11.cell(row = i + 1, column = 8).value = colE[i].value + colF[i].value + colG[i].value

wb_11.save('11.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, if you have values on E1, F1 and G1, you want to have on H1 =E1 + F1 + G1. If that is the case, if you want to write the formula in the cells using python, you can use this command:

```
for row in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    ws['H' + str(row)] = '=E'+str(row)+'+F'+str(row)+'+G'+str(row)
```

Your question was not clear, so if there is anything else, try to formulate it more, maybe editing your original question, or comment here and I'll see what else I can do to help